# Swiper.js with lazy image loading initiating at the wrong height on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have updated my website to have lazy loading images with swiper.js.

When the page loads and swiper is initiated, swiper sets the height of the div containing the slides wrong. Its briefly sets the height to 460px which is the hieght on desktop. When the images are loaded the height is then updated to 186px which is correct for mobile.

I only noticed this after lazy loading was setup.

How can I stop swiper initiating at the wrong size?

This is what it looks like briefly for a second.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcpvh.jpg)

The slide image is prefilled with a placeholder image, width 1200px, height 460px. Then CSS setting the image to width 100% and height auto;

This is my script.

```
    const myswiperban = new Swiper('.swiper-container-ban-wide', {
            loop: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination-ban-wide',
                clickable: true
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-ban-wide',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-ban-wide',
            },
            slidesPerView:1,
            freeMode:true,
            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000
            },
            autoHeight:true,
            preloadImages: false,
            lazy: {
                loadPrevNext: true
            },
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to edit auto height true to auto height false Making these changes will prevent swiper.js from creating an automatic height for your items

```
autoHeight:false, preloadImages: false, 
lazy: { loadPrevNext: true },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly, but the Browser can't know the real `height` and `width` of the image until he has loaded the image. What you can do is add a `height` and `width` onto the images, when you already know them. And remove the initial `height` set by you.
Otherwise you can try to work with `height: 0` and a `transition`, this way it shows the slider after the first image is loaded instead of going from big to small.